# Supabase policy with exception

Tags: supabase

I want to enable RLS in a table to only authenticated users, but there is a row with specific user_id that eveyone can access it without authentication. my current policy looks like this but it doesnt work
`((user_id = auth.uid()) OR (user_id = 'dcb7a8c3-6a5a-4fc1-a3d8-2c1659d8a1b2'::uuid))`

any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you paste either the entire SQL statement to create the policy or a screenshot of the dashboard where we can see all of the definitions of the policy?